# Is there a way to apply an onEdit function to multiple separate ranges in google sheets Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Note - I'm new to coding and apologize in advance if I am asking something dumb or in the wrong format.

Goal - Create a table (not a list) in google sheets with radio button functionality (meaning only 1 checkbox can be selected at a time.)

Code - Here is the code that is working for a list of checkboxes (1 single range)  -

```js
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Sheet1" || e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.value == "FALSE") return;
  for(var i = 2;i<21;i++){
    if(i == e.range.rowStart) continue;
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,2).setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Question - Is there a way to apply an onEdit function to multiple separate ranges in google sheets Apps Script?

Example Sheet: In this example, you'll see there are multiple checkbox ranges in the table: D3:H3, D5:H5, D7:H7, D9:H9

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amhGvT_wf44B_MWm4-J5HJxsXEkbSW4dNTF8OEer28A/edit?usp=sharing)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's that script modified to work with your larger range.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (!e) throw "do not run from editor";

  radioButtons(e);
}

function radioButtons(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  const row = r.rowStart;
  const col = r.columnStart;

  if (src.getName() != "Sheet1" || row < 3 || row > 9 || col > 5 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  let range = src.getRange("A3:E9").getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i=i+2){
    for (let j = 0; j < range[i].length; j++){
      if (range[i][j] == true && i+3 != row && j+1 != col){
        src.getRange(i+3,j+1).setValue("FALSE")
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose function like this could help:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} startEnd
 * A object denoting limits of  a row or column
 * @property {number} start
 * @property {number} end
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} runcriteria
 * @description Describes which rows/columns to run this function
 * @property {startEnd} row
 * @property {startEnd} column
 */

/**
 * A criteria checker for event object e
 * @author TheMaster
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681716
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit}  e
 * @param {Object<string,Array<runcriteria>> } run_in
 * @returns {{result:boolean,editedSheet:GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet}}
 */
const isEditInMyCriteria_ = (
  e,
  run_in = {
    Sheet1: [
      /*Run in Sheet1!D2:I9 or Sheet1!!A9:Infinity*/
      {
        /*2:9*/ row: { start: 2, end: 5 },
        /*D:I*/ column: { start: 4, end: 9 },
      },
      { /*Anywhere after row9*/ row: { start: 9 } },
    ],
    Sheet2: [/*Run everywhere in Sheet2*/ {}],
    Sheet3: [
      { /*Only in rows 5 to rows10 */ row: { start: 5, end: 10 } },
      {
        /*or D15:E25*/ row: { start: 15, end: 25 },
        column: { start: 4, end: 5 },
      },
    ],
  }
) => {
  const criteriaSheetNames = new Set(Object.keys(run_in)),
    editedRange = e.range,
    editedSheet = editedRange.getSheet(),
    editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName(),
    isEditedSheetInRun_in = criteriaSheetNames.has(editedSheetName),
    runcriteria = isEditedSheetInRun_in && run_in[editedSheetName],
    { rowStart, columnStart } = editedRange,
    gte = (a, b, e) =>
      a >= (b[e]?.start ?? -Infinity) && a <= (b[e]?.end ?? Infinity);
  return {
    result:
      runcriteria &&
      runcriteria.some(
        (obj) => gte(rowStart, obj, 'row') && gte(columnStart, obj, 'column')
      ),
    editedSheet,
  };
};
```

To test,

```
const onEdit = e => console.log(isEditInMyCriteria_(e).result)
```

To use,

```
const onEdit = e => {
  const {result, editedSheet} = isEditInMyCriteria_(e);
  if(result){
    //This edit satisfies all my criteria
    //let's do some damage...
    //uncheck all of D3:H3, D5:H5, D7:H7, D9:H9
    editedSheet.getRangeList(["D3:H3", "D5:H5", "D7:H7", "D9:H9"]).uncheck()
    //recheck current checkbox
    e.range.check();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Master. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this working. I pasted both the "general purpose" code and the "to use" code into a new Apps Script file, is that correct?

Comment: @WillWeeks There are multiple `onEdit` functions in your code, so the script might not be executing your desired function. Either combine both functions into a single `onEdit` function, or rename and install one of them, or remove one of them.

Comment: @WillWeeks Try in this [spreadsheet](https://sheets.new): Create checkboxes in ``Sheet1!D3:D9`` and paste code into this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an onEdit for two different sheets

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "TRUE" {
    e.range.setValue("FALSE")
  }
  if(sh.getName() = "Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()); //puts a timestamp in column5
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cooper, unfortunately, this isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Well then I suggest that you supply us with a truth table explaining in greater detail exactly what you want